# error: no matching function for call to ‘constructor’ note: candidates are:

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

class CROSS
{
    public:
    const int x;
    const int y;

    CROSS(int X, int Y): x(X), y(Y)
    {
    }

    ~CROSS() {}
};

CROSS** Generate_Cross_Array(int M, int N)
{
    CROSS** cross;
    cross = new CROSS*[M];
    for(int i=0; i<M; ++i)
    {
        cross[i] = new CROSS[N];
        for(int j=0; j<N; ++j)
        {
            CROSS cross[i][j](i, j);
            printf("%d, %d\n",cross[i][j].x, cross[i][j].y);
        }
    }
     return cross;
}
```

I am trying to create an 2-dimensional object array and initialize it in the function Generate_Cross_Array(int, int), but g++ told me the following:

> In file included from main.cc:3:
>
> cross.h: In function ‘CROSS** Generate_Cross_Array(int, int)’:
>
> cross.h:23: error: no matching function for call to ‘CROSS::CROSS()’
>
> cross.h:10: note: candidates are: CROSS::CROSS(int, int)
>
> cross.h:5: note:                 CROSS::CROSS(const CROSS&)
>
> cross.h:26: error: variable-sized object ‘cross’ may not be initialized

Thank anyone who give me any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to use dynamically allocated arrays, you must provide a default constructor. Something like this is appropriate:

```
CROSS(int X = 0, int Y = 0): x(X), y(Y)
```

If this isn't an option, consider using a standard library container instead, ie `std::vector`.

Comment: +1, just to point out that the problem is at `cross[i] = new CROSS[N];` line, where the compiler cannot construct an array of objects without a default ctor. The line `cross = new CROSS*[M];` on the other hand is OK, because you are allocating pointers to `CROSS` and not invoking any ctor.

Comment: Thank you both very much. I think I have to implement some other method to solve the problem.